# WebAudio API: Is It Possible to Export an AudioBuffer with StereoPanner Node Data?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm looking to export an AudioBuffer to a wav file with a StereoPanner node i.e. I pan a sound all the left and export it panned to the left. I'm wondering if it is possible to export the StereoPanner data associated with an AudioContext?

I have built an AudioSource from an AudioContext, and I have attached an StereoPanner to my AudioSource. I'm able to pan my sound in-browser without issue, and I'm also able to export my AudioBuffer to a file (wav). Unfortunately, when I export my AudioBuffer, none of the StereoPanner data seems to come with it. Is it possible to export StereoPanner data? Or any Audio Node data?

Here is my sample code. I have glossed over some of the wiring details. The `encodeWav` function is being provided by the [audiobuffer-to-wav](https://github.com/Jam3/audiobuffer-to-wav) library.

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();

// file input code

const arrayBuffer = await new Promise(resolve => {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = res => {
    resolve(res.target.result);
  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
});

audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, newAudioBuffer => {
  const newAudioSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  const newStereoPanNode = audioContext.createStereoPanner();

  newAudioSource.buffer = newAudioBuffer;

  newAudioSource.connect(newStereoPanNode);
  newAudioSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
  newStereoPanNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

  const wavBuffer = encodeWAV(audioBuffer);
  const blob = new Blob([wavBuffer], { type: 'audio/wav' });

  // download file code
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  What do you use to pan the audio?  PannerNode? StereoPannerNode?  Are you also modifying the position/orientation  of the AudioListener?  Please update the question with answers.

Comment: @RaymondToy Thanks for responding. Sorry for the delayed response, but I have updated my question for clarification purposes and added sample code. Hope that helps!

Comment: IIRC, you basically just want the output of the stereopanner and to save it in a wav file?

Comment: Yep! That's what I want

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for updating the question with code.

Given the code example, the easiest way to get what you want is to replace the AudioContext with an OfflineAudioContext.  Something like this:

```
const audioContext =
  new OfflineAudioContext({sampleRate: sampleRate,
                           numberOfChannels: 2,
                           length: lengthInFrames});

// Same stuff as above.


audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, newAudioBuffer => {
  const newAudioSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  const newStereoPanNode = audioContext.createStereoPanner();

  newAudioSource.buffer = newAudioBuffer;

  newAudioSource.connect(newStereoPanNode);
  newAudioSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
  newStereoPanNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

  audioContext.startRendering()
    .then(renderedBuffer => {
       const wavBuffer = encodeWAV(audioBuffer);
       const blob = new Blob([wavBuffer], { type: 'audio/wav' });
       // Download file
     });
});
```

If you must use an `AudioContext`, the solution is a little bit more complicated.  You'll have to stick a `ScriptProcessorNode` or `AudioWorkletNode` after the stereo panner to capture the output and save it some where.  When you're done playing the source, you can encode the save data as above.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer to my own question by pouring over the MDN Web Audio API documentation. It appears what I was looking for was the `OfflineAudioContext` with its `startRendering()` method.

Here is a working example:

```
const file = e.target.files[0]; // file input code
const panValue = -1; // pan input as a number between -1 and 1

const arrayBuffer = await new Promise(resolve => {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = res => {
    resolve(res.target.result);
  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
});

audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, newAudioBuffer => {
  const offlineContext = new OfflineAudioContext(
    newAudioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
    newAudioBuffer.length,
    newAudioBuffer.sampleRate
  );
  const offlineSource = offlineContext.createBufferSource();
  const offlineStereoPanner = offlineContext.createStereoPanner();

  offlineSource.buffer = newAudioBuffer;
  offlineStereoPanner.pan.setValueAtTime(panValue, 0);

  offlineSource.connect(offlineStereoPanner);
  offlineStereoPanner.connect(offlineContext.destination);

  offlineSource.start();

  offlineContext.startRendering().then(renderedBuffer => {
    const wavBuffer = encodeWAV(renderedBuffer);
    const blob = new Blob([wavBuffer], { type: 'audio/wav' });

    downloadFile(blob);
  });
});
```